# s3_direct_upload redirects to S3's XML response from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, amazon-s3

NOTE: I am currently developing against Google Chrome 33.0

I have an upload form that looks like:

```
= s3_uploader_form callback_url: importer_create_path, class: "s3-uploader" do
  = hidden_field_tag "Content-Type", ""
  = file_field_tag :file, multiple: true
  = submit_tag "Upload File(s)", class: "btn btn-primary"
```

NOTE: The "hidden_field_tag" is not included in the doc, but S3 gives me an "Access Denied" saying that one of the bucket rules was violated if I do not include that line.

Once the form is submitted, the file uploads and, on completion, the browser is redirected to the XML document:

```
<PostResponse>
  <Location>
    https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/uploads%2F%7Btimestamp%7D-%7Bunique_id%7D-539661a0152fdb07dec27a5cd7d72c16%2F
  </Location>
  <Bucket>buckentname</Bucket>
  <Key>
    uploads/{timestamp}-{unique_id}-539661a0152fdb07dec27a5cd7d72c16/
  </Key>
  <ETag>"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"</ETag>
</PostResponse>
```

I do have`//= require s3_direct_upload` in my application.js, as well as `*= require s3_direct_upload_progress_bars` in my application.css.scss. Furthermore, I have the required:

```
$(".s3-uploader").S3Uploader()
```

in my importer.js.coffee file.

As far as I can tell, I have followed everything outlined in s3_direct_upload's README on Github. Why am I being redirected to an XML file?

It is probably additionally worth noting that when a file is selected from Chrome's filepicker, the file field text remains "No file chosen". When the form is submitted, the file is uploaded (usually) nonetheless.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you managed to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was going about this the wrong way. The issue was that I forgot to include the proper Javascript files. For a better explanation, I recommend looking at the Github issue [here](https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload/issues/155).